# How to fix Katalon Recorder on Chrome

Tags: selenium-ide, browser-automation, katalon-studio, browser-testing, katalon-recorder

I am new to Kalalon Recorder. After installing the Katalon, while opening the plugin, it is opening in a new window.

Is there an option to fix the plugin in the browser, so that we can see both browser and the plugin same time.

I tried different options but nothing worked for me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure this should be tagged [tag:katalon-studio].

Answer (score 0):

As well as the Selenium IDE - Katalon Recorder is supposed to be an extension with a separate window.
I would just suggest a trivial use of snapping windows.